# How to creating anchors for crypto currencies and mapping the native deposit addresses

Tags: horizon, xlm, anchor

Actually I want to create a crypto currency wallet using stellar anchors. I do not want to run a dedicated node for any crypto coin and also not want to depend on any 3rd party service that's why I want to use the stellar anchors.

I have the confusion that if I create the BTC assets in anchor then how I will be able to generate BTC deposit address?

I am confused here so any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks